# html, css, background color to red on the base of a cell value in foreach loop

Tags: html, jquery, css

- here is my html/css code , in 2nd table If in foreach loop there will be any cell
  value = Not Approved ,   then I want to make that row background red. What will be the exact code for that. Doing this on google app script for sending an email as two tables
- table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

  Spreader
                          Hoisting Speed
                          Stiffness Class
                          Hoist Drive Class
                          Lifetime Load Cycles
                          Q Class Classification
                          Gantry Acceleration
                          Trolley Acceleration
                          Lifting Capacity SWL Single Mode
                          Lifting Capacity SWL Twin Mode
                          Eccentricity Longitudinal Percentage
                          Container Weight Single Mode
                          
                            
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                            
                      
        
        
             
                
                                  
                    
                      
                        
                            
                            
                            
                            
                        
                        
                        
                            
                            {?>

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table tr').filter(function() {
return $(this).find("td:contains('Not Approved')").length > 0;
}).css('background','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Approved</td>
<td>Approved</td>
<td>Approved</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Approved</td>
<td>Not Approved</td>
<td>Approved</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Approved</td>
<td>Approved</td>
<td>Approved</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can use `:contains` to check the td text, and filter `tr`s to those which have more than 0 `td` with that text:

```
$('.yourtable tr').filter(function() {
return $(this).find(td:contains('Not Approved')).length > 0)})
.css('background':'red');
```